# Bad Request when creating new container in Tag-Manager

Tags: php, api, google-tag-manager

I use the php sdk to interact with Google Tag Manager. When I run this code

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('xxxx');
    $client->setClientSecret('xxxx');
    $client->setAccessToken($token);

    $container = new \Google_Service_TagManager_Container();
    $container->setName('a-name');
    $container->setTimeZoneCountryId('America/Los_Angeles');
    $container->setTimeZoneId('US');
    $container->setUsageContext(array('web', 'android', 'ios'));

    $tagManager = new \Google_Service_TagManager($client);
    $tagManager->accounts_containers->create('xxx', $container);
```

then an exception is raised: `Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v1/accounts/xxx/containers: (400) Bad Request`.

The container data are the same as in the Google Developer console. A sample-request in the Google Developer Console creates the same Bad Request error.

Any ideas? Is it a API bug?

Comment: It seems you had your timeZoneCountryId and timeZoneId mixed up in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

This post is quit old and my answer is related to the tag manager api v2 but i also struggelt with creating an container (in v2) and just accomplished the task. I share my code here because when i searched for my problem, i endet up here and found no answer... Maybe it helps someone.

So basically after doing all of the auth stuff, here is how you create an container using tag manager v2 api:

```
    $container = new Google_Service_TagManager_Container();
    $container->setUsageContext(['web']);
    $container->setName('yourContainerName');
    $container->setNotes('yourContainerNotes');

    $accountId = 'yourAccountId';

    try {
        $accountContainer = $tagManager->accounts_containers->create('accounts/'.$accountId, $container);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->printH($e->getMessage());
        $this->printH($e->getCode());
    }
```